# Need to enter keystore details manually in Android Studio even though they exist in build.gradle

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, apk, signed-apk

I have the following lines in my "project module" `build.gradle` (i.e. in `/ProjectName/ProjectName/build.gradle`):

```
android {
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            keyAlias "mykeyalias"
            keyPassword "mykeypassword"
            storeFile file("/Users/MyUsername/Documents/AndroidStudio/android_keystore")
            storePassword "mykeystorepassword"
        }
    }
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.2'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.mypackagename"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }

    ...
```

Still, when I click `Build->Generate signed APK...`, I still have to enter everything manually. This used to work before, not sure when it broke. I have double- and triple checked the path to the keystore file.

Any ideas what could be wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because it's working as designed, i-e whenever you select to generate signed apk from `Build->Generate Signed APK` that wizard will always ask you to enter `keystore` information regardless of any configs being mentioned in gradle files ( although you can mark checkbox to remember that info for later use.)

If you don't want to mention keystore infomation while generating build, switch to release variant and just select `Build->Build APK(s)`. It will generate release apk with the signing configs you have mentioned in your `build.gradle` file.